# Modify existing Little Snitch rule to be Effective in all profiles

Tags: mac, firewall

I've been using Little Snitch for a while. I have several profiles set up (e.g. Home, Work, Public, etc). I've been working to generalize some of the rules. E.g. Instead of specifically allowing Firefox on port 80 to each of a thousand different websites, just allow Firefox on Port 80 to anywhere. However, I still end up with duplicates of many of those same rules across profiles.

Is there an easy way to modify an existing rule to be effective in all profiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you could simply move the rule from your current profile into your 'Effective in all profiles' Profile. But rules in your current active profile will override your 'Effective in all profiles' rules which means they have a higher precedence.

And allowing outgoing connections for your browser on http and https should not be a big security risk IMHO.

Comment: I feel like an idiot for not trying to drag and drop the rules. That works. Thanks!